# Django AutoSlugField not considering soft deleted instances by Django Safe Delete

Tags: python, django, slug, soft-delete, slugify

In our `model` we have a `name` and `slug` fields. This is how it looks like:

```
class MyModel(CommonInfo, SafeDeleteModel):
   name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
   slug = AutoSlugField(_('Url'), populate_from='name', unique=True,)
```

For the `slug` field we generate an unique slug every time our `model` is saved.

We are also using `Django Safe Delete` library to soft delete our `model`:

[Django Safe Delete](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-safedelete)

[Django Autoslug](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

That means that for example if we create a new instance of our `model` with Name "My Model" it will auto generate a `slug` that will look like this: "/my-model".

Now let's say we "soft delete" this instance with the `slug` "/my-model". In our database there will be a property `deleted` which contains the date when the `model` was deleted. We don't show this one in our application, it is completely ignored (because it is soft deleted, that's fine).

The problem is that next time we create another one with the same name "My Model" it will auto generate the slug "/my-model" again, not considering that there is already one (which is soft deleted) with the same name and slug. We would need something like "/my-model-1" or whatever that is unique.

We are missing the connection between the `autoslug` and the `safe-delete` libraries, somehow the `autoslug` needs to know that there might be soft deleted ones and consider them when generating the unique `slug.`

Any help would be really appreciated and please consider that we are totally new in Django / Python.

if this doesn't work, our workaround will be generating the `slug` using 2 fields (name & id). It will generate a `slug` that will look like this: "/my-model/12345" and will be always unique since `id` is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we found it.

We needed to create a new Manager that can see all the instances, even the soft deleted ones:

```
class MyModelAllManager(SafeDeleteManager):
_safedelete_visibility = DELETED_VISIBLE
```

Then in our `model` we pass it to the `AutoSlugField` function:

```
class MyModel(CommonInfo, SafeDeleteModel):

   # We don't know why but it only works if we create a variable and assign the Manager to it. It doesn't work if we pass the Manager directly to the AutoSlugField function.
   all_objects = MyModelAllManager()

   name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
   slug = AutoSlugField(_('Url'), populate_from='name', unique=True, manager=all_objects)
```

That does the magic.